# Follow links with BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python to extract links from a page:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if 'http' in link['href']:
        links.append(link['href'])
```

How do I construct something that opens each link and extracts text from say "p" tags on the linked pages?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `requests` to get the HTML for collected links and then parse it with `BeautifulSoup`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# get links
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if link['href'].startswith('http'):
        links.append(link['href'])

# visit links and print paragraphs text
for link in links:
    response = requests.get(link)

   soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

   for p in soup.find_all('p'):
         print p.text
```

Or without two iterations over links

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# get links
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if link['href'].startswith('http'):
        response = requests.get(link['href'])

         soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

         for p in soup.find_all('p'):
             print p.text
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the way you get the original links, maybe something like:

```
links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)

for link in links:
    # code to create soup of the current link html
    if 'http' in link['href']:
        links.append(link['href'])
```

It would then continue on to the newly added links until completion.