# BeautifulSoup4 and Pandas, follow links in table to download another table, concatenate tables into one Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

> Note: The question and code has been heavily edited as there were
> errors in my original posting and I tried the suggested answer but all
> the values were placed in one column of a dataframe.

I followed this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64636320/13865853

So now I can get the first table but in the column "more" there is a link so I tried this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36753529/13865853
My script:

```
"""
get knapsack food table and table at link "more"
"""

import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
from langdetect import detect

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
url = "http://www.knapsackfamily.com/LunchBox/top.php"

#prepend to links
def prepend(arr, str):
    str += '{0}'
    arr = [str.format(i) for i in arr]

    return arr

# data for first post request    
data={
    #hidden type values and submit name and value
    'mode': 'list3',
    'fword1': '',
    'model': ' List All'
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(url, data=data).content, 'html.parser')

stuff = []
for row in soup.select('table.sortable.d1 tr'):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select('td, th')]
    stuff.append(tds)

for i in range(10):
    print(stuff[i])

#stuff[0] are the headers
# make dataframe and concantenate the next results 

# follow links
links = []
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if link['href'].startswith('list'):
        links.append(link['href'])



url_prefix = "http://www.knapsackfamily.com/LunchBox/"
links_arr = prepend(links, url_prefix )
#visit links and get the cells I want:
en_pages = []
count = 0
print('here')
for link in links_arr:
    print(f'count: {count}\nlink: {link}\n')
    response = requests.get(link)

    soup_next = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    en_pages.append(soup_next)
    count+=1
    if count > 5:
        break

en_stuff = []
for page in en_pages:
    for row in page.select('table.rs2 tr'):
        tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row.select('td, th')]
        en_stuff.append(tds)
        
       
# filter English tables later


#if row in English
#if detec(row_text)=='en':
 #   en_stuff.append(row_text)
print("raw rows")
for table in en_stuff:
    print(table)

print("df's")
df_arr = []
count = 0
for table in en_stuff:
    next_pg_df = pd.DataFrame(table)
    df_arr.append(next_pg_df)
    print(next_pg_df)
    count+=1
    if count > 5:
        break
```

I limited it to 5 just so I can see what is happening.
The output for 'raw rows' is:

```
['大分類', '植物', 'Kingdom', 'Plant']
['種名', 'Abelmoschus esculentus', 'Species', 'Abelmoschus esculentus']
['学名(一般名)', 'Abelmoschus esculentus[okra、おくら、オクラ、秋葵、あめりかねり、アメリカネリ、おかれんこん、オカレンコン、陸蓮根]', 'Latin Name(General Name)', 'Abelmoschus esculentus[okra]']
['科名', 'アオイ科', 'Family', 'Malvaceae']
['原産/分布', '東北アフリカアフリカエチオピア近辺が原産。', 'Origin', 'Origins:Northeastern AfricaAfricaaround Ethiopia']
.
.
.
```

So if I take the third element as a dataframe column name and the fourth element as the value in that column for the first organisum and then just add the fourth element as a column value for organisms that follow, I could make a dataframe.
The output for "df's" looks incorrect as it is putting everything in one column:

```
         0
0      大分類
1       植物
2  Kingdom
3    Plant
                        0
0                      種名
1  Abelmoschus esculentus
2                 Species
3  Abelmoschus esculentus
                                                   0
0                                            学名(一般名)
1  Abelmoschus esculentus[okra、おくら、オクラ、秋葵、あめりかねり、...
2                           Latin Name(General Name)
3                       Abelmoschus esculentus[okra]
           0
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

in the last line of your first solution instead of printing the list create dataframe from the list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(en_stuff)
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting that, I edited my question to reflect what I learned from you.